# How do you organize an application with a list of items, which link to a lot of activities?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an application and I can't figure out what's best to do.

> I have a long list of tableRows. About 200 of them. They are different
>   models of a specific product. Each row, when clicked, should show a
>   screen with that item's specs for the user to read.

Here are my options, I would need help and guidance on how to do each one of these as I am a beginner (but I'm getting more advanced)

### First Approach

Create an activity for each and every item. The user will click the row and then they will have to press back to get back to the list. (I know how to do this. I'm fine with this)

### Second Approach

I read about horizontal page swiping. Similar to the Play Store. I would prefer this option, but would I be safer sticking to lots of activities?
When the user clicks a row, it would bring them to the item spec and they will be able to swipe left and right between all the items. Pressing back will bring them back to the list.
(This is the one I need full step-by-step guidance with, so I can learn for the future, thanks)

Does anyone have any other suggestions how I would handle this amount of data?

Thanks

Comment: Don't start a new activity when you press these buttons. Instead display a Toast or Dialog. Can you be more specific about "different models of a specific product"

Answer (score 0):

You have a long list of items. That suggests you use a ListActivity to show the items. If the items have similarities, use one view to show them and one Activity to show details. If the items are totally different, use different layouts to inflate in getView and different activities. Having the items in one list suggests, however, that there are similarities and it's best to use one layout in the listview and one activity for details.

Alternatively, you can group your items according to similarity in the way you show them. You may end up with ten different views to use in the listview, and ten different activities.

Comment: They are all totally different. So each one would need its own layout. Would having too many activities slow the device down?